# Prevent Downloads from browser back and forward buttons

Tags: javascript, session, ruby-on-rails-4, download, back

I am using rails4 and in my controller page I have xl download like below.

Everything works fine but when I use the browser's back and forward buttons, it is downloading the same content again and again. How can ? get rid of it?

```
  def download_report
    @acquisitions = AcquisitionReport.generate(params[:acquisition_id].to_i, params[:portfolio_id])

    cookies[:fileDownload] = 'true'
    render xlsx: 'download_report',filename: "report.xlsx"
  end
```

Comment: Just curious, why are you storing it in cookies?

Comment: Think he is trying to maintain cookie to prevent downlaod

Comment: @AmitBadhekaPykihStaff, It is for, In order to make JQuery knows the file download just occurred.  If it not there, the dialog box does not go off after the fle completes its preparing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think, You have to maintain sessions

```
def download_report
  @acquisitions = AcquisitionReport.generate(params[:acquisition_id].to_i, params[:portfolio_id])

  if session[:test] == true
     session[:test] = nil
     render xlsx: 'download_report',filename: "report.xlsx"
  else
     render :nothing => true, :status => 200, :content_type => 'text/html'
  end
end
```